# PS3 slow loading on all games when using hard drives bigger than 160GB+

Tags: ps3

Has anyone run into the issue of having a slow loading system? Currently any game I put in the system takes about 2-3 minutes just to load into the title screen. I tested this with Last of Us. I'm using a 500GB. Also switched it out with a 160GB and does the same thing. Anyone run into the same issue?

Comment: Tested anything other than The Last of Us? TLOU has a very slow initial load

Comment: yes tried a bunch of other games. same issue. loads very slow.